# Android tunnel in a separate service

Tags: android, android-service

I'm writing a secure application which supposed to run the communications to private servers in an ssh tunnel.
What I need is for the application to open the tunnel when it starts and to close it when the app finishes (Exits).

Is there a way of doing such thing on the application level rather than on an activity level?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in `Application.onCreate()`, however there isn't any call when the app exits. At some point, Android will just kill the OS process hosting the app.

If this isn't suitable, use a `Service` and setup/teardown your tunnel in the `Service`.